# How to show a set is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,0,0,...,0): x_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with usual topology.

I know that I have to show $(\overline{A})^{0}=\emptyset$. But I couldn't find $\overline{A}$. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\overline{A} = A$ because of $(x_n) \in A, x_n \to x$, then each component of $x_n$ converges to the corresponding component of $x$. Hence,
   $$
   x(j) = 0 \quad\forall j\geq 4
   $$
   which implies $x\in A$
2. If $x\in A$, and $\epsilon > 0$, then the element $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ given by
   $$
   y = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \epsilon/2, 0, 0, \ldots)
   $$
   satisfies $\|x-y\| < \epsilon$, but $y\notin A$. Hence, $B(x,\epsilon)$ is not contained in $A$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to show that $A$ is closed, so $A = \overline{A}$; consider sequences in $A$. But $A$ has empty interior: For given any $x \in A$ and $r > 0$, the ball $B(x, r)$ contains a point with non-zero fourth coordinate.